# SAS: Looping through a table, and inserting rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, multidimensional-array, sas

Beginner here, and I hope this isn't to vague a question.

BACKGROUND: I have a table with Inventor ID's linked to Years. Which represents all the years the Inventor registered a patent.

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE Inv_Year AS
       SELECT a.InventorID, a.Year
       FROM Inv_Year_Pat AS a;
QUIT;
```

So the rows look like this

```
InventorID | Year
1            1989
2            2002
3            1990
3            1992
3            1994
```

TASK: Inventor number 3 invented in 1990, 1992 and 1994. Well I need to fill in any year in-between the inventor's active years. Resulting in this...

```
InventorID | Year
1            1989
2            2002
3            1990
3            1991
3            1992
3            1993
3            1994
```

How do I solve this problem in SAS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by InventorID ;

  prevYear = lag(Year) ;
  if first.InventorID then prevYear = . ;

  /* If not first row per InventorID and difference is > 1 year */
  if not missing(prevYear) and sum(Year,-prevYear) > 1 then do ;
    /* Store current Year */
    thisYear = Year ;
    /* Insert missing years */
    do Year = prevYear + 1 to thisYear ;
      output ;
    end ;
  end ;
  else output ;

  drop prevYear thisYear ;
run ;
```